# How to change color on hover of SVG base64

Tags: css, svg

CSS:

```
.img-smiley  {
    background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    display:block;  
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <div class="img-smiley">
        </div>
    </a>
</body>
```

How should I change color on hover from original to green?

Comment: Write some javascript to extract the data from the URL, change it and then replace the url with a new url which has the different colour baked into it.

Answer (score 2):

Hi instead of `background-image` use `mask-image` and then change the `background-color` color on hover... kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/v3n0g8zt/1/

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <div class="img-smiley">
        </div>
    </a>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-smiley 
{
  background-color: red;
    -webkit-mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    mask-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");

    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    display:block;  
}

.img-smiley:hover{
    background:green;
}
```

Comment: mask images are not working on mozilla n ie  browser. this code is working on crome. it shows rectangle instead of smiley.

Answer (score 1):

The current color of the image is something that's embedded inside the image's encoding and something that CSS can't know anything about, so in order to change it you need another base64 image and set it as the background.

Assuming the green base64 green image in base64 is `data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPS`, you can do something like this:

```
.img-smiley:hover {
    background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPS");
}
```

Or use the smiley character if it fits your needs and style it accordingly. Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/wmZVB/5/

Comment: can we use something like fill color.

Comment: You could, but your smiley would have to be written entirely in CSS. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** you have to encode your SVG html tag or SVG image in the base 64 format. Here is the [link](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/image/svg) to convert from SVG to base 64.

**Next** you have to set your encoded base64 to the background-image property.

**For ex:**

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"); width:32px; height: 32px; background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

**Final Step** for **hover**: You have to convert that SVG to base64 by changing the stroke and fill color of the path inside SVG tag .

**EX:**

```
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"); width:32px; height: 32px; background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

*You can try by pasting this code on your HTML page and run.*